# Removing a commit from a git branch

Tags: git, git-rebase

git version 1.7.5.4

```
commit 142e37219a68955ded79fbd9faa83cb4585b02ca
Merge: 6e9b88f 1b141fd
Author: Steve
Date:   Wed Oct 31 10:56:51 2012 +0700

    Merge branch 'dev-video' into 'dev-video_res-management'

commit 1b141fd4ca697d1626da807bc32325a657544678
Author: Steve 
Date:   Wed Oct 31 10:42:41 2012 +0700

    FIXED:
```

Is there anyway I can remove the commit commit commit 142e3

For some reason I am getting a problem with that commit and I would like to delete so I can test without it.

When I am tried:

```
git rebase i 142e3
```

I could not see it, I can only see the ones before and after:

```
pick 6e9b88f FIXED: ...
pick 1b141fd FIXED: ...
```

The reason I asked was because I merged this into another branch I am not sure it can be removed.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [git revert](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html):

```
git revert 142e3
```

Comment: What would the parent number be?  The current mainline branch is dev-video and I merged that into dev-video-res_management. I just want to remove this commit. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. If you need to revert merge - add `-m` key: git revert -m 142e3. Read this: http://opensource.apple.com/source/Git/Git-26/src/git-htmldocs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt